# basic function and relation concepts

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, inverse-function

I was given problems to do over the summer in preparation for my graduate course study; however, it has been about 2 years since my discrete mathematics days and I am really stumbling on a couple problems. Below I listed two problems that are giving me problems. I am not really searching for answers, but explanations of how to do each one because I know how important these concepts are.

1. Let X := R. For A, B ⊂ R, we say A ≥ B if B ⊆ A. Is this relation complete, symmetric, transitive, and/or reflexive?

I know what each "thing" (complete, symmetric, transitive, reflexive) is and I could answer this with ease, but I don't know how to deal with an inequality between sets. A and B are both sets I believe and I don't know how to say set A would be greater than set B.

2. Let f : R → R with f(x) := x^3, A := (−8, 1) and B := [−1, 8]. Find f(A) and the inverse of f(A).

This problem is giving me a problem because A and B are sets. It is extremely easy, when A is a given number. My best guess was to just plug in the -8 into the equation and the 1 into the equation for the inverse, but I don't think this is right.

Any help is appreciated. I know these problems a basic problems, but for some reason I just cannot remember the material. Thanks

Comment: Does the second one actually say 'the inverse of $f(A)$', or does it say $f^{-1}(A)$?

Comment: I apologize it is the latter, but I wasn't sure how to put that into the paragraph

Comment: There's a MathJax tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can right-click on any typeset formula, select `Show Math As`, and then select `TeX Commands` to see how the expression was coded.

Answer (score 1):

For 1., we are simply declaring "$A \ge B$" to mean $B \subseteq A$, i.e. $B$ is a subset of $A$.

For 2., in general $f(A)$ denotes $\{f(x) : x \in A\}$, that is, the set of all possible values $f$ takes when you plug in things from $A$. This is known as the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)) of $f$.

<s>I'm not sure what "inverse of $f(A)$" means.</s>

Likewise, $f^{-1}(A)$ denotes $\{x : f(x) \in A\}$, that is, all things in the domain ($\mathbb{R}$) that after plugging into $f$, gives something in $A$. This is the ["inverse image" or preimage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) of $A$.

Comment: The second answer makes total sense, but is there any way you can explain number one further? Does that mean all the items in B are less than or equal to an item in A and that B is a subset of A?

Comment: @DanOffenbacker No, it just means that everything in $B$ is also in $A$. For example, the interval $[1,2]$ is a subset of $[0,3]$ since everything between $1$ and $2$ is also between $0$ and $3$. So we write $[1,2] \subseteq [0,3]$. Note that $[1,2]$ contains numbers that are larger than some numbers in $[0,3]$ (e.g., $1.5$ is in $[1,2]$ and is larger than $0$).

Comment: Oh ok! So this problem is fairly simple in asking if B⊆A is complete, reflexive, symmetric, transitive! Thank you again.